# Get-Content command Powershell understanding

Tags: powershell, powershell-2.0

I am trying to figure out as why these commands are not running via script. But when I run this manually it's working.

```
$value = Get-Content c:\info.txt | select-string Id | Foreach-Object { $_.ToString().split(':')[1] -replace '\s','' } 
Write-Host "$value" >> c:\list.txt
```

I have tried to redirect out using >> but still there is no information gets updated in variable $value

```
Get-Content c:\info.txt | select-string Id | Foreach-Object { $_.ToString().split(':')[1] -replace '\s','' } >> $value
    Write-Host "$value" >> c:\list.txt
```

Comment: What is the content of `c:\list.txt`? We can provide you with a better command. What is it you're really trying to do?

Comment: it's just to check that if my information is getting stored in a variable, so I am printing the output in a text file(c:\list.txt).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You cannot redirect `Write-Host`. You need to remove that. The following example will do what you are asking:

```
Get-Content "C:\info.txt" | select-string Id | Foreach-Object { $_.ToString().Split(':')[1] -replace '\s','' } >> "C:\List.txt"
```

...though I'm not sure what the string manipulations are for, since I don't know what the content of C:\Info.txt looks like.

If you simple want the output to be placed into `$value` rather than being redirected to a file, you would write it like this:

```
$value = Get-Content "C:\info.txt" | select-string Id | Foreach-Object { $_.ToString().Split(':')[1] -replace '\s','' }
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt response!!! I am looking Get-Content info to be stored into variable $value

Comment: See updated answer - instead of redirecting, assign to variable.

Answer (score 0):

To write content to a file you'll want to use `Set-Content` or `Add-Content`. In your case you'll want to use `Add-Content` as that will append rather than overwrite the data much like the `>>` stream re-director does. `Write-Host` should usually be avoided in PowerShell scripts outside of specific cases, more on that [here](http://windowsitpro.com/windows/write-output-or-write-host-powershell).

```
$value = Get-Content c:\info.txt | select-string Id | Foreach-Object { $_.ToString().split(':')[1] -replace '\s','' }
Add-Content -Path C:\list.txt -Value $value
```

The reason `Write-Host` did not produce any output in the script is because it bypasses sending the object to the PowerShell objectflow engine and instead directly to the console host, which, depending on your scripts execution environment may not be what you expect.